# Get mean along axis but with different subset of that axis in each cell

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I need the mean along the time axis of array (1), using numpy.

The catch: it's not going to be the mean of all values along this axis, but rather a subset that starts at an index that is given in array (2).

The arrays I'm working with:

```
 (array1) 3 axes: time, x, y
array([[[ 820,  820,  720,  720],
        [ 860,  860,  500,  500],
        [ 860,  860,  500,  500],
        [ 860,  860,  500,  500]],
       [[5980, 5980, 4760, 4760],
        [7500, 7500, 7940, 7940],
        [7500, 7500, 7940, 7940],
        [7500, 7500, 7940, 7940]],
       [[ 740,  740,  440,  440],
        [1240, 1240, 1140, 1140],
        [1240, 1240, 1140, 1140],
        [1240, 1240, 1140, 1140]],
       [[3200, 3200, 7600, 7600],
        [ 900,  900,  400,  400],
        [ 900,  900,  400,  400],
        [ 900,  900,  400,  400]]])
 (array2) 2 axes: x, y 
array([[  1,   2,   1,   1],
       [  1,   0,   3,   3],
       [  4,   0,   2,   2],
       [  4,   0,   1,   2]])
```

To illustrate the example further:

Values in array1 represent rainfall per day at locations x/y.
Values in array2 represent from which day on the mean needs to be calculated for location x/y.

Looking at the first cell, we would exclude the first day from the calculation, as array2[0,0] = 1. So our result would be np.mean(array1[1:, 0, 0]) = 3306.67.

What I can't wrap my head around is how to specify the subset for each cell based on array 2. I know I can use np.mean along any axis, but how can I dynamically exclude values (slice the array) from the calculation?

Comment: How large is your data and how fast does the solution need to be? You can do this using iteration very easily but it won't be fast and vectorized.

Comment: We're talking about millions of observations.
A for loop would have been my first thought as well, but that's not the best idea working with large raster data in the array space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr1 = np.array(
    [[[ 820,  820,  720,  720],
      [ 860,  860,  500,  500],
      [ 860,  860,  500,  500],
      [ 860,  860,  500,  500]],
     
     [[5980, 5980, 4760, 4760],
      [7500, 7500, 7940, 7940],
      [7500, 7500, 7940, 7940],
      [7500, 7500, 7940, 7940]],
     
     [[ 740,  740,  440,  440],
      [1240, 1240, 1140, 1140],
      [1240, 1240, 1140, 1140],
      [1240, 1240, 1140, 1140]],
     
     [[3200, 3200, 7600, 7600],
      [ 900,  900,  400,  400],
      [ 900,  900,  400,  400],
      [ 900,  900,  400,  400]]]
)
```

```
arr2 = np.array(
    [[  1,   2,   1,   1],
     [  1,   0,   3,   3],
     [  3,   0,   2,   2],
     [  3,   0,   1,   2]]
)
```

what we're trying to do is slice the time axis of `arr1` using the indices stored in `arr2`, now python only allows slicing using `:` which we can only pass while indexing literally, ie not using another array for indexing. so we need a round about way of doing it

one way could be to change all the values in `arr1` ,that would've been ignored if sliced, to `0`

now to find the indices of the values to be ignored we do this

```
no_days = arr1.shape[0]
arr3 = np.arange(no_days)
arr3.shape = [-1,1,1]
arr3

>>> [[[0]],

     [[1]],

     [[2]],

     [[3]]]
```

```
filter = arr3 < arr2
filter.shape

>>> (4, 4, 4)
```

`arr3` is an array of indices of time axis. we compared it with `arr2` and now we have boolean indices of values to be ignored in `filter` and we can set them to `0`

```
arr1[filter] = 0
arr1

>>>   [[[   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,  860,    0,    0],
        [   0,  860,    0,    0],
        [   0,  860,    0,    0]],

       [[5980,    0, 4760, 4760],
        [7500, 7500,    0,    0],
        [   0, 7500,    0,    0],
        [   0, 7500, 7940,    0]],

       [[ 740,  740,  440,  440],
        [1240, 1240,    0,    0],
        [   0, 1240, 1140, 1140],
        [   0, 1240, 1140, 1140]],

       [[3200, 3200, 7600, 7600],
        [ 900,  900,  400,  400],
        [ 900,  900,  400,  400],
        [ 900,  900,  400,  400]]]
```

we might be tempted to use `arr1.mean(axis= 0)` but in doing so also considers all the `0`s legitimate entries which effects the mean, instead of ignoring them

so instead we sum `arr1` over time axis and devide it by no of elements that would've been in the slices

```
arr1.sum(axis= 0) / (no_days - arr2)

>>>   [[3306.66666667, 1970.        , 4266.66666667, 4266.66666667],
       [3213.33333333, 2625.        ,  400.        ,  400.        ],
       [ 900.        , 2625.        ,  770.        ,  770.        ],
       [ 900.        , 2625.        , 3160.        ,  770.        ]]
```

if `t < x*y` then the following would perform faster

```
arr1.sum(axis= 0) / (~filter).astype(int).sum(axis= 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually just used the filter array to create a np.ma.masked_array so I can use array.mean().

Answer (score 1):

I found a way using [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/groupby.html).
It isn't really pretty, but at least I believe that it is vectorized.

First, convert numpy arrays to xarray `DataArray`, and put both in a `Dataset` by using `xr.merge`:

```
rainfall = xr.DataArray(rainfall, dims=("day", "x", "y"), name="rainfall")
start_idxs = xr.DataArray(start_idxs, dims=("x", "y"), name="start_idxs")

ds = xr.merge((rainfall, start_idxs))
```

Here what a `Dataset` looks like:

```
>>> ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (day: 4, x: 4, y: 4)
Dimensions without coordinates: day, x, y
Data variables:
    rainfall    (day, x, y) int64 820 820 720 720 860 ... 400 900 900 400 400
    start_idxs  (x, y) int64 1 2 1 1 1 0 3 3 4 0 2 2 4 0 1 2
```

Then we want to make different computation based on the `start_idxs` variable, so we'll `groupby` this data variable:

```
>>> groups = ds.groupby("start_idxs")
>>> groups
DatasetGroupBy, grouped over 'start_idxs' 
5 groups with labels 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.
```

You see that there is 5 groups as expected. Now we want to apply a computation for each group, so we'll use `map`.

```
>>> res = groups.map(mean_start_idxs, args=("day",))
>>> res["rainfall"]
<xarray.DataArray 'rainfall' (x: 4, y: 4)>
array([[3306.66666667, 1970.        , 4266.66666667, 4266.66666667],
       [3213.33333333, 2625.        ,  400.        ,  400.        ],
       [          nan, 2625.        ,  770.        ,  770.        ],
       [          nan, 2625.        , 3160.        ,  770.        ]])
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y
```

This is the expected output. Note `nan` values where it was asked to begin the mean from the index 4, with only 4 days that's not possible.

But for that to work we need to define the `mean_start_idxs` function, and that's the tricky part.

It's tricky because it is not straigthforward to retrieve the "label" of the groups from inside the function called by `map`, but here is a solution:

```
def mean_start_idxs(ds, dim):
    # Get the start indice
    #   groups were made from start_idxs, so we can
    #   take any value of ds["start_idxs"] as a start indice
    start = ds["start_idxs"][0].item()
    end = ds.sizes[dim]

    return ds.isel({dim: slice(start, end)}).mean(dim=dim)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have never used xarray and it's not available in the environment I'm working with at the moment. The package does look interesting though and I'm curious to find out more about xarrays now.